# sqlplus trying to find out proc description

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Via sqlplus if I type

`desc STORED_PROC_1`

I get nice parameters list.

However when I type

`desc SOME_OTHER_PACKAGE.STORED_PROC_2`

I get `ORA-04043: object SOME_OTHER_PACKAGE.STORED_PROC_2 does not exist`
And that object does exist (I can exec it). So why is this so? I don't have rights or what?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but the [SQLcl command line tool has an info command](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/01/sqlcl-commands-info-info-the-new-desc/) which does let you describe an individual procedure/function within a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `DESCRIBE` command it is possible to describe ENTIRE the package. e.g. `DESC SOME_OTHER_PACKAGE` 

Describing just a single procedure within the package **is not possible**

You'll find more info on SQLPlus's commands here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm